# Comparing keys of a dictionary within a dataframe column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I've a dataframe like -

```
Challenge       Points
challenge1      {'k01-001': 0.5, 'k03-015':0.3, 'k01-005': 0.2}
challenge2      {'k02-001': 0.5, 'k06-003':0.4, 'k04-001': 0.1}
challenge3      {'k04-001': 0.1, 'k06-003':0.9}
challenge4      {'k01-005': 0.2, 'k01-001':0.4, 'k03-002': 0.2, 'k01-007': 0.2}
challenge5      {'k06-003': 0.6, 'k04-001':0.4}
```

From here I want to make a dictionary where the keys should be the tuples of two points that have been evaluated together for a challenge (eg. `('k01-001', 'k01-005')`) and the value should be how many challenges they have been evaluated together in. So, something like -

`{('k01-001', 'k01-005'): 2, ('k01-001', 'k03-015'): 1, ('k01-005', 'k03-015'): 1, ('k04-001', 'k06-003'): 3, ... }`

I've so far managed to read individual dictionaries in the `Points` column using this code -

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    dict_temp = json.loads(row['Points'].replace("'", '"'))    
    for key, value in dict_temp.items():
        # SOME CODE HERE
```

but, I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: do you want a dictionary for each row?

Comment: No, a dictionary for the whole dataframe.

Comment: are there repeats challenge rows?

Comment: No, the `Challenge` column has all unique values, but two (or more) challenges can have the same `Points`.

Comment: Can you do to_dict() of your dataframe ?

Comment: @YOBEN_S I've already converted each row value to a dictionary (code above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `map` and `reduce` with defaultdict to count:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import reduce
from itertools import combinations
```

---

```
combs = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, 
               map(lambda x: tuple(map(sorted, combinations(list(x), 2))) ,
                   df['Points']))

d = defaultdict(int)
for comb in combs:
    d[tuple(comb)] += 1
d = dict(d)
print(d)
```

---

```
{('k01-001', 'k03-015'): 1, ('k01-001', 'k01-005'): 2, ('k01-005', 'k03-015'): 1,
 ('k02-001', 'k06-003'): 1, ('k02-001', 'k04-001'): 1, ('k04-001', 'k06-003'): 3,
 ('k01-005', 'k03-002'): 1, ('k01-005', 'k01-007'): 1, ('k01-001', 'k03-002'): 1, 
 ('k01-001', 'k01-007'): 1,('k01-007', 'k03-002'): 1}
```

Time comparison:

```
%%timeit
combs = reduce(lambda x,y: x + y, 
               map(lambda x: tuple(map(sorted, combinations(list(x), 2))) ,
                   df['Points']))

d = defaultdict(int)
for comb in combs:
    d[tuple(comb)]+=1
d = dict(d)
26.2 µs ± 439 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

---

```
%%timeit
s=(df.Points.apply(lambda x: tuple(itertools.combinations(x.keys(), 2))).explode()
    .apply(lambda x : tuple(sorted(x))).value_counts()).to_dict()
1.69 ms ± 62.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: It gives me keys for each character - eg. `('"', '{'): 804, ('S', '{'): 190, ('-', '{'): 402 ...`

Comment: I think type of your cell is str and not dict, maybe you need: `df['Points'] = df['Points'].apply(eval)` before

Comment: I have used your data frame as an example. Cells must contain dictionaries, but I think yours contain string..
so with the other solution it gives you the error of str does not have the attribute keys, keys is an attribute of the dictionaries ...

Comment: Yes it works with `apply(eval)` .. thanks a lot!! :)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC we need `itertools` to get the `combination` then we do `explode` , and `sorted` the value within the `tuple` and `value_counts`

```
import itertools
s=df.Points.apply(lambda x: tuple(itertools.combinations(x.keys(), 2))).explode().apply(lambda x : tuple(sorted(x))).value_counts()
Out[543]: 
(k04-001, k06-003)    3
(k01-001, k01-005)    2
(k02-001, k04-001)    1
(k01-005, k03-002)    1
(k01-005, k03-015)    1
(k01-001, k03-002)    1
(k01-001, k03-015)    1
(k01-001, k01-007)    1
(k01-005, k01-007)    1
(k01-007, k03-002)    1
(k02-001, k06-003)    1
Name: Points, dtype: int64
```

If you need `dict`

```
s.to_dict()
Out[546]: 
{('k04-001', 'k06-003'): 3,
 ('k01-001', 'k01-005'): 2,
 ('k02-001', 'k04-001'): 1,
 ('k01-005', 'k03-002'): 1,
 ('k01-005', 'k03-015'): 1,
 ('k01-001', 'k03-002'): 1,
 ('k01-001', 'k03-015'): 1,
 ('k01-001', 'k01-007'): 1,
 ('k01-005', 'k01-007'): 1,
 ('k01-007', 'k03-002'): 1,
 ('k02-001', 'k06-003'): 1}
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'` the code I had above converted the strings to dicts. How can I do the same with this?